# Canvas not shown on page using Raphael.js in web2py

Tags: raphael, web2py

Goal: use Raphael.js to draw data chart/lines in web2py framework.

What I have learned from http://raphaeljs.com/ is that, I just need to include the JS into the HTML page and then I can use the APIs. But here is what I have done:

(1) First, I copied both raphael.js and raphael-min.js to myapp\static\js folder.
(2) Then I wrote these in the HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{=URL('static','js/raphael.js')}}">

window.onload = function() {
var paper = new Raphael(0, 0, 100, 100);
var circle = paper.circle(50, 50, 50);
circle.attr("fill", "#f00");
circle.attr("stroke", "#fff");
}
</script>
```

This file is periodically loaded to a div in the index.html.

I expected a circle could be shown but nope, though I was very sure this page was periodically loaded.

Did I do anything wrong here (of course I did)? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try using separate script tags to load the library and then run your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{=URL('static','js/raphael.js')}}"></script>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
var paper = new Raphael(0, 0, 100, 100);
var circle = paper.circle(50, 50, 50);
circle.attr("fill", "#f00");
circle.attr("stroke", "#fff");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Aha! I finally find out what the problem is! Just need to move the include to the div in the index.html. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly your question but instead of importing just one and then writing the other in the file, you can do it all in one src assigning like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{=URL('static','js/raphael.js')}} {{=URL('static', 'other_function.whatever_extension}}">
```

This will import both scripts. You can add as many as you wish and even change the paths.